# Take text from a file and insert to a mysql table using a script

Tags: mysql, bash

I would like to take data (some text) from a file and insert it into a mysql field, using a script.

`I have tried: mysql -u root -p password dbname << INSERT INTO tblename (fieldname) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('filename'));`

and

`mysql -u root -p password dbname << EOF INSERT INTO tblename (fieldname) VALUES ('$filename'); EOF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not even close for either. You can't "redirect" a string into mysql.

Try

```
echo "INSERT INTO tblename (fieldname) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('filename'));" | mysql -u root -p password dbname
```

instead.

The second version has even less of a chance to work - you'd just be inserting the name of the file into the database, not the file's contents.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I did not know you could do it that way. I have given you a one up, but it is still not taking the data from the file and putting it in the field, it just comes up with null in the field. Im using Ubuntu if that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of script? If this is in bash, you could do something like:

mysql -u root -p password dbname << EOF INSERT INTO tblename (fieldname) VALUES ('`cat /path/to/file.txt`'); EOF