# Populate MySQL table using txt file and bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, sed, awk

I am trying to write a bash script that will take a text file and use its content to populate a MySQL table.

The text file contains numerous entries that I will need to add to the table.

Example of text file contents:

```
Firstname=bob
Surname=ross
Age=9
Firstname=gary
Surname=graeme
Age=19
Firstname=henry
Surname=harry
Age=23
```

The text file is structured like the example above, the same 3 variables are constantly assigned new values for each unique entry that would go into the mysql table.

I have used sed to remove all empty lines and lines beginning with "#" in the text file that I would not want to process.

My question is how do I use bash to make an sql insert every three lines using the contents in textfile to generate the mysql query. I know I need to loop through the file 3 lines at a time until the end of the text file is reached and somehow parse each value after "="
and assign it to a variable in the loop iteration to insert the mysql data but I am not sure how to do this.

I know that I will need to have a new table entry every 3 lines.

```
echo "INSERT INTO $table (Firstname, Surname, Age) VALUES ('$Firstname', '$Surname', '$age');" | mysql $db
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split each line in the input on `=` and use the second part.
Then I pipe this to the `while`-loop where I use `read fname sname age` to populate the variables inside the loop. I use `NR % 3==0 {print("")}` to introduce a linebreak in the output every three lines.

```
awk -F"=" '{printf("%s ", $2)}; NR % 3==0 {print("")}' input_file | \
while read fname sname age; do
    echo "INSERT INTO $table (Firstname, Surname, Age)
      VALUES ('$fname', '$sname', '$age');" | mysql $db
done
```

**UPDATED:**
input:

```
Firstname=bob
Surname=ross
Age=9
Activity=1 2 3 4 5
Firstname=gary
Surname=graeme
Age=19
Activity=1 2 3 4 5
Firstname=henry
Surname=harry
Age=23
Activity=1 2 3 4 5
```

with this code:

```
awk -F"=" '{printf("%s ", $2)}; NR % 4==0 {print("")}' input | \
while read fname sname age act; do
    echo "'$fname', '$sname', '$age', '$act');" 
done
```

gives:

```
'bob', 'ross', '9', '1 2 3 4 5');
'gary', 'graeme', '19', '1 2 3 4 5');
'henry', 'harry', '23', '1 2 3 4 5');
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. I have introduced a few more variables there are a total of six now - this isn't a problem I just changed the modulus condition. The last one is a string though. E.g. (Activity=I walked the dog). With this awk I am only capturing the first word of the string to be stored in this field. Any ideas?

Comment: actually it should still work.. because `read a b c` will read a complete line, split on whitespace (default) and then put the first token in a, the second in b,... but if there are more token than variables provided it puts all the remaining tokens into the last variable. see: `read a b c <<< "1 2 3 4"; echo $c;` gives `3 4`

Comment: Note that this only works if there's one variable that has multiple words, and it has to be the last one. Also, the string can't contain '='.

Comment: @Barmar why did you revoke your solution?

Comment: @Barmar now I see what you mean with "only works if there's one variable that has multiple words"... and revoke you solution...

Comment: I thought I was wrong about the awk part. Because you use -F=, the string will always be $2. But that was before I realized that an embedded '=' will mess it up. So the right solution is `$1 = ""; printf("%s ", $0)`.

Comment: So I am not really sure what you are saying here - how will I store the full string as an entry in the last sql column?

Comment: @Barmar sorry,...but I was also a bit confused. You are right that I use `-F"="` and therefore `$2` should contain the remainder of a line after `=` (provided there is just one `=` on a given line)...point - Then you do not need `$1 = ""; printf("%s ", $0)`... So the `awk` part should work. But the `read` part should also work as I already pointed out above. **Note:** Only because the Activity field is the last in a given record.

Comment: @Mixiul I have updated my answer...If its still not working for you please provide an example where it fails..

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to change the structure of file, just try to use `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` instruction. Detailed specification is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). It's a lot faster than you would write it by yourself :)

If not, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066854/take-text-from-a-file-and-insert-to-a-mysql-table-using-a-script).